# Node.js not found by Rails / execjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, centos, execjs

I have node.js installed by compiling and installing it from the root user. I think this maybe where the hangup is. From the user running the rails app I checked for node.js.

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

When I launched my rails  app (Rails 3.2.9) I get the universally unhelpful "We're sorry, but something went wrong." Checking the the production error log I saw that the Javascript runtime was not found. That's confusing as it is obviously installed. So I went about forcing the Node javascript runtime. I edited config/boot.rb to include:

```
ENV['EXECJS_RUNTIME'] = 'Node'
```

I checked my app again, while watching the production log. This time I got the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system
```

Still confused. I went to the execjs gem and changed the runtime command to the exact installed path.

```
Node = ExternalRuntime.new(
  :name        => "Node.js (V8)",
  :command     => "/usr/local/bin/node",
  :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/node_runner.js",
  :encoding    => 'UTF-8'
)
```

I still get the same error. Node is installed and accessible by the user but the gem/rails can't seem to use it.
The server is run CentOS 6.3. The specific javascript file causing the error to be thrown is jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js. Which I didn't edit after downloading it from nivo.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I have a fedora box and serve an app using phusion passenger. I had to restart the app though, after I changed the runtime command, as you indicated above for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar issue installing nodejs with source on my centos 6.3 system. It was successfully installed but I keep failing in compiling my ror app assets until I explicitly set the PATH to where it was installed (nodejs)

[root]# make install
...
installing /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/html/doc/folders.html
symlinking ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js -> /usr/local/bin/npm
updating shebang of /usr/local/bin/npm to /usr/local/bin/node

[root]# export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Now it works. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

So, I have Ruby 2.0.0 installed and Rails 4.0.2 on CentOS 5.10 using Apache2 with Passenger.  My first step I tried was opening the rails console and typing in the following command:

```
ExecJS.runtime
```

It returned the following value:

> #<ExecJS::ExternalRuntime:0x99ab380 @name="Node.js (V8)", @command=["nodejs", "node"],@runner_path="/home/foo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.1.0
>   /lib/execjs/support/node_runner.js", @encoding="UTF-8", @deprecated=false, @binary="node">

Which meant that node was indeed installed and detected, but for some reason it was not working.

So, I tried the example on the website:

```
ExecJS.eval("'red yellow blue'.split(' ')")
```

and I got the correct response.  So, now I am wondering why Passenger isn't picking it up.

Then, I noticed that passenger shows the path variable and it looks like:

> /home/foo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/foo/bin

But, it seems to be missing the `usr/local/bin`.  I'm no expert on Linux, so for me the easiest way to fix this is with a symbolic link. So, I execute `ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node`.  You may want to note that I found the path to my nodejs using the command `find / -name node`.

I then refreshed my web application and wouldn't you know it worked.  So, if it worked for me I am hoping that it can help someone else out.

**UPDATE (Probably Better Way):**  This is probably a better way to do it.  We can compile it from source like so:

```
mkdir ~/install
cd ~/install
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.2.1/node-v7.2.1.tar.gz
tar xvf node-v7.2.1.tar.gz
cd node-v7.2.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/
make && make install
```

This way Node.js will be installed in the path where Passenger expects it to be.

Comment: Well, I searched for hours until I found this. 
My nodejs was fully installed, and your solution solved my problem. 
Although using a symlink doesn't look like the best solution....
Anyway, thanks!!

Comment: Where did you see that Passenger is looking for node in different path?

Comment: @simo this was almost  5 years ago so I don't remember but I think it was in the console after running the commands as listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but check your $PATH that node is in there.  Also, you should be using rvm if you want to use node. Check that your node install is done correctly.