# Python - Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I'm getting the following error when trying to use ExecJS:

```
execjs.RuntimeUnavailable: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system
```

I have node.js installed on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04). `Which Node` outputs `/usr/bin/node`

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install node.js, via the default repos, added a repo, nvm?

Comment: Digital Ocean - NodeJS package

Comment: Can you output `execjs.get().name`? Have you tried setting a `EXECJS_RUNTIME` environment variable to `"Node"` explicitly?

Comment: @tsturzl `_auto_detect raise RuntimeUnavailable("Could not find a JavaScript runtime.") execjs.RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime.`

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable posted above?

Comment: Try `ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs` Looking at the source it basically just tries both of these commands. Perhaps there is a bug that fails to find the node.js runtime unless its added to your environment as `nodejs`. Ubuntu usually installs node.js executable to the path `/usr/bin/nodejs` rather than just `/usr/bin/node`. So perhaps there is a bug that slipped through the cracks because the may be using a ubuntu box for testing. I'm not certain, but its worth a shot.

Comment: Either way I would classify this as a bug. I'd recommend creating a ticket at [the PyExecJs github](https://github.com/doloopwhile/PyExecJS/issues). The code isn't that complicated otherwise, its just looking to see what runtimes exist then passing the JS as an argument to one of the available runtimes. I'd imagine you can just adjust the library to find your runtime and send a PR to the maintainer.

Comment: Alternatively you can still use V8 via the `PyV8` dependency, however this doesn't include commonjs or core modules from node.js and will likely be a different version of V8. I'm not sure if you need/want these things or not, but it may be a quick and easy fix.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`? Perhaps your environment is jacked up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187681/node-js-not-found-by-rails-execjs)

They resolve the problem by linking node under `/usr/local/bin/node`

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for as my `Which Node` already outputs `/usr/bin/node` so creating a link from local wouldn't do anything

Comment: This worked for me in getting Intellij Idea to recognize node installed via NVM

Answer (score 2):

Hello I've had the same issue before and this solved it:

[Node.js not found by Rails / execjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187681/node-js-not-found-by-rails-execjs)

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to use ExecJS, what user are you trying to run as? the ENV path for node may be not be available to the account which is trying to execute the ExecJS. May be this could be a dumb idea but have you tried re-installing nodejs?

sudo apt-get install nodejs

Answer (score 0):

To get some insight what's happening, you might want to try "strace yourapp" (system call tracer), or strace -p $PID , (-f helps following forks) then grep the output for node. You will see what it was trying to open/start before throwing the error.

That way you will have something to look for in configuration or environment, that must be changed to the path your node could really be found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you really have file `/usr/bin/node`. If it is a symlink, make sure the target is exists and valid.

I know that `which node` gave you the result but just make sure it's same in the python's environtment.

```
print os.environ.get('PATH', '')
```

And make sure your `/usr/bin/node` is executable by current user.

```
$ node --version
```