# Python - Node.js\PyV8 (V8) runtime is not available on this system

Tags: python, execjs

I'm pretty much completely new to python (though I have programming experience in other languages), and at the moment, I'm simply trying to get a script to work.

I'm trying to use a batch downloader script, and it currently throws this error:

> EnvironmentError: Your Javascript runtime 'JScript' is not supported due to security concerns. Please use Node.js, V8, or PyV8.

So, I head into pyexecjs to set the environment, but then that throws this error:

> > > node = execjs.get("Node")
>
> execjs.RuntimeUnavailable: Node.js (V8) runtime is not available on this system

I did install nodejs through pip and I have confirmed it is installed. I also have PyV8 installed but I get an identical error if I try to set the runtime to it as well. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991263/python-node-js-v8-runtime-is-not-available-on-this-system) as well as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187681/node-js-not-found-by-rails-execjs) (dealing with the Ruby version) but neither really helped me understand what I'm doing incorrectly. Thank you very much for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same exact issue as you and installing https://nodejs.org/en/ itself help fixed this issue , i had the same question as you some i did some googling to come up with that answer hope it helps!

Comment: I just tried installing it; I did a reset, and I'm still throwing the same error.